# Excel VBA - Autofill a Column according to InputBox

Tags: excel, vba

Current Outcome

```
A1     B1
Item   Deposit to
Apple  Trash
Banana 
Grape
```

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myValue As Variant
myValue = InputBox("Enter Where", "Deposit to", Trash)
Range("B2").Value = myValue
End Sub
```

1. Trying to get the Value from the Input to auto-fill for the entire Column B as long as there is a value in Column A.

Attempted to place this with the Command Button, but can't seem to get it to work.

```
Sub test()
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B3:B" & lastRow)
End Sub
```

Desired outcome

```
A1     B1
Item   Deposit to
Apple  Trash
Banana Trash
Grape  Trash
```

2. Is there a way to Prompt for value without the CommandButton?

At the moment, the CommandButton Works for the InputBox, but when i attempt the code to autofill it removes the Input and leaves blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `InputBox()` anywhere in code, generally, to prompt for input. You can separate that from your Command Button code.

For the first part, you can use this formula.  Where there's a value in column A, put the input in column B:

```
Sub t()
Dim myValue As String
Dim lastCel As Range

Set lastCel = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
myValue = InputBox("Enter Where", "Deposit to")

Range("B2:B" & lastCel.Row).Formula = "=IF($A2<>""""," & """" & myValue & """" & ","""")"
Range("B2:B" & lastCel.Row).Value = Range("B2:B" & lastCel.Row).Value


Range("B2").Value = myValue
End Sub
```

Edit:
The `.Formula` line is doing just as it reads - it's adding a formula to the range.

If you're in the worksheet, and in cell `B2` enter the formula `=IF($A2<>"","Bruce","")` it will check if cell `A2` is Empty.  If it's *not* empty, it will return `Bruce`.  If `A2` *is* empty, will return an empty string `""` (which in practical terms just returns a blank cell.).

*Then* if you drag that formula from `B2` down to `B1000`, the formula will update row by row...so `B3` would have `=IF($A3<>"","Bruce","")`, and cell `B4` would have `=IF($A4<>"","Bruce","")`, etc. etc.

The VBA line in question selects the range, say `B2:B1000`, and applies the formula `=IF($A2<>"",myValue,"")` thus returning the `myValue` variable when the same row's column A is not empty.

(Don't get confused by the `""""`.  Since our original formula contains quotes `If($A2<>"" <--` in VBA you have to basically double up...otherwise VBA would interpret that line as just `"=IF($A2<>"`and then throw an error.  That `"""" & myValue & """"` surrounds the `myValue` variable in quotes for the formula. If you just did `=IF($A2<>""""," & myValue & ","""")"` then you'll get an error, since `myValue` is being used like a named range/function/not a string.  Try it and see what I mean).

Comment: Thank you for this. I am  in the process of learning VBA Script. I am really bad so far at combining code. Oddly I understand all the code you have written except this line;

Range("B2:B" & lastCel.Row).Formula = "=IF($A2<>""""," & """" & myValue & """" & ","""")"

Comment: @Neil - See the edit.  Hopefully that helps to clarify! If not, explain and clarify a little more what you're not understanding and I'll try to help clarify further.

Comment: Thanks BruceWayne for the in-depth explanation. That helps out a lot.